# Jython : ImportError: No module named scipy in <script> at line number 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, jython-2.7

I am trying to run the below code using the **`Jython`**:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); // ouput will be stored here
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();
context.setWriter(writer); // configures output redirection
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
engine.eval("import sys");
engine.eval("import scipy");
```

But getting below error while running:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named scipy in <script> at line number 1
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.scriptException(PyScriptEngine.java:202)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:42)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:31)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at com.spark.test.JythonExample.main(JythonExample.java:46)
Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy

    at org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Py.java:328)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:877)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:972)
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:1062)
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1280)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:431)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1232)
```

Can anyone please help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: Why did you expect that to work? SciPy doesn't support Jython. Even regular Python doesn't come with SciPy; it's a library you'd have to install.

Comment: I have already installed `scipy` on my machine. When i run a script directly from terminal it works fine but when i run it through the `jython` it shows the above error.

Comment: Your `scipy` runs with a regular `python`.  `jython` uses its own third party modules; it can't borrow them the `python`.  And there isn't a `numpy` or `scipy` for `jython`.

Comment: @Hokam , Did u get any solution for this?